# Specify no-fetch in package.json or config.xml

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is there a way to specify `no-fetch` inside a configuration file so that when people check out my code and do `npm install` it doesn't fail for plugins that are not available via npm registry?

If I manually do it on command line, its fine. I'd like `no-fetch` to be automatically invoked. Thanks

Comment: More than 1 year with this cordova issue breaking our brains...

Comment: I gave up. I forked all those plugins and registered my forks in npm with my own namespace.